# Matching classes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I have two unordered lists, a bit like:

```
<ul class="list1">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li class="current">Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list2">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

And the goal is, with jquery, to identify which li is marked with the 'current' class and then add a class to the second list to the corresponding li.  I just can't think of how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with corresponding? The content (`Item 4`) or the position?

Comment: From the comments he seems to mean the **position**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('ul.list2 li:nth-child(' + $('ul.list1 li.current').index() + ')').addClass('current');
```

Or you could make it a little less icky:

```
$('ul.list2 li').eq($('ul.list1 li.current').index()).addClass('current');
```

The second one, I like better, now that I get to see them both :-)  The tricks here are:

1. the "eq" filter lets you pick an element from a jQuery list based on an index;
2. the "index" function lets you *find* the index of an element relative to its siblings in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

```
// Find the current item in the first list, remember its text
var textToMatch  = $('ul.list1 li.current').text();
// Loop through each li in the second list
$('ul.list2 li').each(function(index, domElement){
     var curr = $(domElement);
     // if the text matchs the first then add our class
     if(textToMatch == curr.text()){
          curr.addClass('NEWCLASS');
     }
 });
```

EDIT1:This is answering the wrong question, the question has since been clarified I will leave this here as it still seems nice :)

EDIT2: as Per Flex, this is a nicer way to achive the same thing, again not what the question was after.

```
$('.list2 li:contains("' + // Find an li in list2 which contains
    $('.list1 li.current').text() + '")')  // the same text as the as the current li in list1
    .addClass("NEWCLASS"); // and add our new class to it
```

Comment: I assumed we where looking for elements of the second list with the same text. Other answers assume you mean at element of the same index in the second list.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear - it's the same index (not necessarily text)

Comment: This can be done easier with `:contains`: `$('.list2 li:contains("' + $('li.current').text() + '")').addClass("whatever")`

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use this:

```
var initialIndex = $('.list1 .current').index();
$('.list2 li').eq(initialIndex).addClass('current');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('li.current + li').addClass('yourClass')
```

edit: misunderstanding of the question

```
var index = $.inArray($('li.current')[0],$('li.current').parent().children());
$('ul:eq(1) li:eq('+index+')').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: Is this even a valid jQuery selector? And what should the `+`-sign mean in the selector. And how/why should this work at all?

Comment: @jitter: http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/ It is valid but not selecting the right elements.